# how to check IOS devices supported by my IPA file

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, ipa

I wanted to check `iOS` devices supported by my `IPA` files i.e. whether `IPA` file supports ipad or iphone devices.

I have checked in info.plist but didn't got any information like this.
can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 5):

You can check [`UIDeviceFamily`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW11) key in the `info.plist` file

> Xcode inserts it automatically based on the value in the Targeted Device Family build setting. You should use that build setting to change the value of the key.

Answer (score 1):

The info plist has info (should :D) [device family, sdks version vs. deployment version, required capabilities(!)]

&

the executable's architectures are also relevant (see with lip --info)